# C# object initialization of read only collection properties

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

For the life of me, I cannot figure out what is going on in the example piece of C# code below.  The collection (List) property of the test class is set as read only, but yet I can seemingly assign to it in the object initializer.

** EDIT:  Fixed the problem with the List 'getter'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace WF4.UnitTest
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        private List<string> _strCol = new List<string> {"test1"};

        public List<string> StringCollection 
        {
            get
            {
                return _strCol;
            }
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class UnitTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void MyTest()
        {
            MyClass c = new MyClass
            {
                // huh?  this property is read only!
                StringCollection = { "test2", "test3" }
            };

            // none of these things compile (as I wouldn't expect them to)
            //c.StringCollection = { "test1", "test2" };
            //c.StringCollection = new Collection<string>();

            // 'test1', 'test2', 'test3' is output
            foreach (string s in c.StringCollection) Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that unusual `get` is going to cause confusion, btw...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This:

```
MyClass c = new MyClass
{
    StringCollection = { "test2", "test3" }
};
```

is translated into this:

```
MyClass tmp = new MyClass();
tmp.StringCollection.Add("test2");
tmp.StringCollection.Add("test3");
MyClass c = tmp;
```

It's never trying to call a setter - it's just calling `Add` on the results of calling the *getter*. Note that it's also not *clearing* the original collection either.

This is described in more detail in section 7.6.10.3 of the C# 4 spec.

EDIT: Just as a point of interest, I was slightly surprised that it calls the getter twice. I expected it to call the getter once, and then call `Add` twice... the spec includes an example which demonstrates that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that section of the c# spec.  After reading through it I can see where that syntax is defined.  Personally, I don't see why they would want to allow that syntax (it looks like you are assigning a new set of elements to a property)... or maybe I just think that because I've been writing too much JavaScript lately :)

Comment: @markdb314: It's there because it's incredibly useful. It's not at all unusual to allow a caller to *manipulate* a collection but not *replace* it.

Comment: You explained why the unusual code _does_ work, but I still don't understand why the first line of commented-out code _doesn't_ work. Given your explanation, I would expect `c.StringCollection = { "test1", "test2" };` to be allowed and work the same. But the OP says it doesn't compile.

Comment: @JesseWebb: Collection initializers are only allowed in object creation expressions - either directly on the newly created collection, e.g. `new List<string> { "x", "y", "z" }` or embedded within an object initializer. `c.StringCollection = { "test1", "test2" }` is just an assignment - there's no object creation expression there.

Answer (score 13):

You aren't calling the setter; you are essentially calling `c.StringCollection.Add(...)` each time (for "test2" and "test3") - it is a *collection initializer*. For it to be the *property* assignment, it would be:

```
// this WON'T work, as we can't assign to the property (no setter)
MyClass c = new MyClass
{
    StringCollection = new StringCollection { "test2", "test3" }
};
```

Comment: @remi -look at the `get`; every time you call `get` it returns a collection with just "test1"

Comment: @markdb314 I already answered that... **every** time you call that `get`, your code creates a new list. You should really have the list as a field on the class.

Comment: @markdb314: If you actually back your property with a *field* (which could be initialized via another collection initializer) then you'll end up with a more consistent property... instead of creating a new list on each getter call.

Comment: @markdb314 Because of this line `return new List<string> { "test1" };` in `get` it always returns new list with one element "test1"

Comment: @Marc , oh yes ! I didn't see it, my bad. Thank for your answer.

Comment: For completeness, `private readonly List<string> items = new List<string> { "test1" }; public List<string> StringCollection { get { return items;}}` should fix that.

Comment: ok, duh.  of course that's why it is only returning "test1", my bad.  but i still don't understand where that syntax comes from?  for example, why doesn't c.StringCollection = { "test1", "test2" } do the same thing when placed outside an object initializer?

Comment: public class MyClass
        {
            private List<String> list = new List<string>() { "test1" };
            public List<string> StringCollection 
            {
               
                get
                {
                    return list;
                }
            }
        }

Comment: @markdb314: Because collection initializers are only valid as part of an object-creation-expression (section 7.6.10 of the C# spec).

Comment: thanks @Jon - I didn't have the spec numbers to hand; obliged ;p

Answer (score 0):

I think that, beeing read only, you can't do

```
c.StringCollection = new List<string>();
```

But you can assign items to list...
Am I wrong?

Answer (score -1):

The `StringCollection` property doesn't have a setter so unless you add one you cannot modify its value.