# Add to a readonly collection in a constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor, readonly-collection

Is there a c# language construct that will allow me to add items to a readonly collection property in a constructor?  I want to do something like this:

```
public class Node{
    public IList<Node> Children {get; protected set;}
    public Node(){
        Children = new ObservableList<Node>();
    }
}
```

... in my code somewhere...

```
var node = new Node {Children.Add(new Node())};
```

(not a great example, but I hope this gets the idea across)...

**UPDATE**

OK sorry I need to be clearer.  I didn't write this `Node` class, and I cannot change it.  I am asking if there is a c# language concept that will allow me to add to the readonly collection in the parameterless constructor in the second snippet, assuming the `Node` class is not changeable.

Comment: Hiding the `set` doesn't make the collection immutable, if you can get a reference to the IList, you can invoke `Add` on it.

Comment: The `readonly` keyword only applies to fields - not properties. It also only protects the field itself, not the object it's referencing. So adding `readonly` to a ObservableCollection wouldn't make the actual collection readonly, just the field that's referencing it.

Comment: @Chris yeah I got rid of it... that's what I get for "coding from the hip"...

Comment: What you're trying to achieve? you mean `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel no I want to accomplish something vaguely like the second code snippet, where I can instantiate an object and add something to the collection property in one go.

Comment: And you can add later? or you want to restrict it only in object construction?

Comment: I don't have access to the `Node` class, the code for that just represents what it looks like externally.  I'm looking for a way to write my second snippet given the first snippet cannot change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this. It is definitely possible to add elements on construction

```
var node = new Node
 {
     Children =
    {
        new Node(),
        new Node()
    }
 };
```

Comment: but the `Children` property doesn't expose a public setter, so the caller can't assign a new collection to that property.

Comment: @Servy Try it out, This works. it doesn't need a public setter.

Comment: @Servy Look at my snippet, this is not assignment, this is actually **collection initialization**

Comment: @SriramSakthivel And the result of the collection that you initialize with a collection initializer is then *assigned* to a property using the property setter.

Comment: @Servy You have mistaken. Again, this is not an assignment. this will work for `readonly` fields also. What makes you to think this is an assignment? `public readonly IList<Node> Children;` mark field as `readonly` still this will work. pls try it out. This even works when property is `get only`

Comment: he's right, it does work, I didn't know the compiler was that clever :) a note though, this only works if all the elements are added explicitly, if you want to add them via a list, you'll need a helper method

Comment: @aL3891 OMG at least one person understood me. Thank you. So many people are not aware of this feature and that is the reason my answer is being downvoted :(

Comment: It seemed there had to be a way to do this, but I couldn't figure out how to do it.  It does seem counterintuitive, but I tossed this into my constructor and it worked exactly as desired, when a property assignment blew up on me.

Comment: That's so bizarre. It seems like a good follow up question might be "why does this behaviour happen"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646285/c-sharp-object-initialization-of-read-only-collection-properties

Comment: @PrestonGuillot Thanks for the link...I just asked a question on that which now seems like a duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/q/19305074/1324019

Answer (score 0):

If you have a property of type List that is `get` only, that only means you can't set that property, you can still add things to the list.

You could however expose an `IEnumerable` property instead and have a constructor that takes a list(or another `IEnumerable` more likely).

Property initializers do not work since the compiler will just rewrite them to regular property assignments.

I'd do this:

```
public class Node{
    public IEnumerable<Node> Children {get; private set;}
    public Node(IEnumerable<Node> children){
        Children = children.ToList();
    }
}
```

---

if you can't change the `Node` class, I suggest writing a helper class similar to this:

```
public static Node Create(IEnumerable<Node> children)
{
    var n = new Node();
    foreach (var c in children)
        n.Children.Add(c);
     return n;
}
```

Comment: Well I didn't actually write the `Node` class.  I am referencing it above to indicate how it looks from the outside.  I am just instantiating the class, and in just about every instantiation, there are multiple child nodes I must also instantiate.  I was hoping for a nice language construct in the constructor that would allow me to make it work in one statement.

Answer (score 0):

To use the collection initializer syntax from you second code snippet your Node class must implement IEnumerable and have a public method with the signature

```
void Add(Node child)
```

Hence such a class cannot offer the immutability you desire. I think the best solution to your problem would be to do this

```
public class Node
{
  public readonly IEnumerable<Node> Children;

  public Node(IEnumerable<Node> children)
  {
    Children = children;
  }
}
```

or if you do not like the deferred execution of IEnumerable:

```
public class Node
{
  public readonly ReadOnlyCollection<Node> Children;

  public Node(IEnumerable<Node> children)
  {
    Children = new ReadOnlyCollection<Node>(children);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add a backing field to the "Children" property, then just populate the backing field during construction.

Like so

```
public class Node
        {
            private IList<Node> _Children;
            public IList<Node> Children { get { return _Children; } }
            public Node(IList<Node> children)
            {
                _Children = children;
            }
        }
```

Then you can do this

```
var node = new Node((new ObservableList<Node>()).Add(new Node()));
```

Comment: The class yes, the call I'm not sure, he really should pass a collection as the parameter. Maybe not, I had to remove the default value.

Comment: I removed the default value from the constructor, and it compiled.  The answer has been updated.

Comment: much better now, check out my answer