# Why does collection initialization ignore access modifiers?

Tags: c#, .net, access-modifiers

Spawing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19304642/1324019), some code appeared that seems to not make sense:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = new Testing
        {
            ListOfStrings =
            { 
                "hello", 
                "goodbye" 
            }
        };

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Testing
{
    public List<string> ListOfStrings { get; private set; }

    public Testing()
    {
        ListOfStrings = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

At first glance one would think this code wouldn't compile: after all `ListOfStrings` is supposed to have a private setter, and shouldn't be able to be assigned to in this manner.

However, this code compiles and runs fine, and `t.ListOfStrings` has the values assigned.

Why does this collection initialization ignore the private setter?

Comment: You're setting its elements not creating a new type of List<string>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example you are not actually setting the property.

C# is smart enough to know that you are using an ICollection which can be publicly modified using Add, Remove, Clear, etc.  What you are doing is the equivalent of this:

```
t.AddRange(new string[] { "hello", "goodbye" });
```

If you actually tried to do this it would not work:

```
var t = new Testing
{
    ListOfStrings = new List<string>(),
};
```

**EDIT:**

Since you might be wondering how to expose a collection as readonly, you can do this by just exposing it as an IEnumerable:

```
public class Testing
{
    private List<string> _listOfStrings;
    public IEnumerable<string> MyStrings
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (var s in _myStrings)
                yield return s;
        }
    }

    public Testing()
    {
        _listOfStrings = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

You could also create a readonly collection but I find that is more confusing.  If you expose it as IEnumerable then consumers of the class can enumerate through the items with no ability to add or remove items.

Comment: I don't think it will be translated to `AddRange`. It will Call `Add` `Add`

Comment: "which can be publicly **cleared** and added to": the collection isn't cleared; if the constructor adds something to it, it will stay there...

Comment: Nope, `AddRange` will call `CopyTo`if parameter is `ICollection<T>`

Comment: Right, I meant more in the sense that a public List can be added to, removed, and cleared regardless of the property accessor.

Comment: Edited to show how to expose a non-modifiable collection.

Comment: @TrevorElliott that doesn't prevent mutation. If user is clever he can find it is actually a `List` so he can simply mutate it with a cast to `List<T>`

Comment: @Sriram Not if you implement your own enumerator.  But if you're trying to protect your classes from consumers of your assembly you will never be successful.  They could use reflection to modify private variables directly without much trouble.

Comment: It's not about security, it's about bug-free code and using classes how they are intended.

Comment: I know that but your example is very simple. I'll suggest `myList.AsReadOnly()` as simple as that :)

Comment: I wouldn't do that, it's more confusing because it still exposes Add, Remove, Clear methods.  You might try to use one of those functions and then later realize it's throwing an exception.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does this collection initialization ignore the private setter?

It doesn't. This collection initialization syntax :

```
    var t = new Testing
    {
        ListOfStrings =
        { 
            "hello", 
            "goodbye" 
        }
    };
```

is actually transformed by the compiler to something like this:

```
var t = new Testing();
t.ListOfStrings.Add("hello");
t.ListOfStrings.Add("goodbye");
```

So as you can see, `ListOfStrings` isn't actually assigned a new value...

Comment: I found another question than answered mine just after I posted! Thanks for the answer regardless...