# dynamically create and add item to TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel

This is the code that i currently have to dynamically create a TableLayoutPanel.

```
TableLayoutPanel searchResults_tableLP = new TableLayoutPanel();
searchResults_tableLP.ColumnCount = 2;
searchResults_tableLP.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
searchResults_tableLP.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
searchResults_tableLP.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
searchResults_tableLP.Name = "tableLayoutPanel" + i;
searchResults_tableLP.RowCount = 1;
searchResults_tableLP.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
searchResults_tableLP.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
searchResults_tableLP.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 100);
searchResults_tableLP.TabIndex = 0;
```

However how do I turn that into this. I dont know nor can I find the syntax to add `ColumnStyles` and `RowStyles`

```
TableLayoutPanel searchResults_tableLP = new TableLayoutPanel
                        {
                            ColumnCount = 2,
                            Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3),
                            Name = "searchResults_tableLP" + i,
                            RowCount = 1, 
                            Size = new System.Drawing.Size(612, 59),
                            TabIndex = 0,
                        };
```

And how do i dynamically add content or controls to the table?
Example I want to add a text to the first or second column? How would i go around doing that. This seems such an easy answer but I can not find it anywhere.

Comment: Just do this first in the designer.  Then look in the InitializeComponent() method, it shows you exactly what code you need to write.  Or copy/paste.

Comment: @HansPassant I tried that but it doesnt show the syntax on how to add colum and rows. And i dont know how to add text

Comment: Erm, it certainly does.  Click the "Size Type" radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

ColumnStyles is a readonly property, it created when TableLayoutPanel init.

[Add to a readonly collection in a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304327/add-to-a-readonly-collection-in-a-constructor)