# Add CodeCommentStatement to CodeMemberProperty When Generate C# code with CodeDOM

Tags: c#, codedom

Does anyone know how to Add CodeCommentStatement to CodeMemberProperty When Generate C# code with CodeDOM ?

I tried:

```
var docStart = new CodeCommentStatement("<summary>", true);
var docContent = new CodeCommentStatement("The description of property", true);
var docEnd = new CodeCommentStatement("</summary>", true);

var property = new CodeMemberProperty {
    Name = name,
    HasGet = true,
    Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public | MemberAttributes.Static,
    Type = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(byte[]))    
};

var documentation = new CodeCommentStatementCollection { docStart, docContent, docEnd}
property.Comments = new CodeCommentStatementCollection(documentation);
```

But Comments property hasn't setter...

[image]

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd propose to add the items to the existing `CodeCommentStatementCollection` instead of creating a new one:

```
CodeCommentStatement[] documentation = { docStart, docContent, docEnd}
property.Comments.AddRange(documentation);
```

The collection provides the common methods for adding: [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codecommentstatementcollection.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yc364h03%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for an array, [AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxcz873b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for a CodeCommentStatementCollection.

As pointed out by **@svick** in the comments, you can also assign the value when instantiating the object, e.g.

```
var property = new CodeMemberProperty {
                   // Other initialization values
                   Comments = { docStart, docContent, docEnd } }
```

In case you wonder why and how this works on a readonly property, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5646285/642579) and its answer.

Comment: And you can do this in an object creation expression too: `new CodeMemberProperty { Comments = { docStart, … } }`.

Comment: @svick: Thanks for your addition. Took me some time to figure out how this works on a readonly property - I've definitely learned something new today. I've updated the answer.