# Why can I use an anonymous collection initializer with a read-only auto-property while I can't use an object initializer

Tags: c#

Consider the following class with a read-only (or getter-only) property **ClientPermissions** :

```
internal class Client
{
    public string? ClientId { get; set; }

    public HashSet<string> ClientPermissions { get; } = new(StringComparer.Ordinal);

    public HashSet<string> ClientTokens { get; set; } = new(StringComparer.Ordinal);

}
```

It seems I can't assign an object during construction to the read-only auto-property ClientPermissions while I can assign it values with an anonymous collection initializer

[SO 5646285](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646285/c-sharp-object-initialization-of-read-only-collection-properties) gives a hint
that for the object initializer the dotnet compiler actually compiles this into using object creation and then addition of the values.

Ok.. but why can I use an anonymous collection initializer than with this read-only auto-property?

```
        // Works - no complaints from compiler when I use collection initializer on read-only auto-property ClientPermissions
        var sc1 = new Client() { ClientId = "c1", ClientPermissions = { "a1", "b1" }, ClientTokens = { "t1", "t2" } };

        // Works - no complaints from compiler when I use collection initializer on read-only auto-property and object initializer on normal/full auto-property
        var sc2 = new Client() { ClientId = "c2", ClientPermissions = { "a1", "b1" }, ClientTokens = new HashSet<string>{ "t1", "t2" } };

        // DOES NOT COMPILE - Compiler complains with a CS0200: Property or indexer '...' cannot be assigned to -- it is readonly
        // auto-initialize syntax 
        var sc3 = new Client() { ClientId = "c3", ClientPermissions = new HashSet<string> { "a1", "b1" }, ClientTokens = new HashSet<string> { "t1", "t2" } };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is calling the `Add` method on the object referenced by `ClientPermissions`:

```
ClientPermissions = { "a1", "b1" }
```

It is not assigning a new object to that property, hence why it is allowed.

This, conversely, is invalid, because you cannot assign a new object to that property after construction:

```
ClientPermissions = new HashSet { "a1", "b1" }
```

The relevant documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#object-initializers-with-collection-read-only-property-initialization).

Answer (score 2):

That hint you found is exactly the reason.

If you use a collection initialiser on the right hand side of `ClientPermissions =`, the setter of `ClientPermissions` is not called, as the post you linked says. The generated code is:

```
Client client = new Client();
client.ClientId = "c3";
client.ClientPermissions.Add("a1");
client.ClientPermissions.Add("b1");
HashSet<string> hashSet = new HashSet<string>();
hashSet.Add("t1");
hashSet.Add("t2");
client.ClientTokens = hashSet;
```

Whereas if you use `= new HashSet<string> { ... }`, then you are calling the setter of `ClientPermissions`, because the thing after the `=` (i.e. `new HashSet<string> { ... }`) is an expression. Note that this expression also has a collection initialiser inside it, that is processed separately.

```
Client client = new Client();
client.ClientId = "c3";
HashSet<string> hashSet = new HashSet<string>();
hashSet.Add("a1");
hashSet.Add("b1");
client.ClientPermissions = hashSet; // setter called here!
HashSet<string> hashSet2 = new HashSet<string>();
hashSet2.Add("t1");
hashSet2.Add("t2");
client.ClientTokens = hashSet2;
```

Think of it like this: the `ClientPermissions = new HashSet<string> { ... }` case is treated like any other `Property = expression` initialiser in an object initialiser. On the other hand, the `ClientPermissions = { ... }` case is the "special" syntax that you can only do in object initialisers and it is where `Add` is called, rather than assigning the RHS to the LHS.